# Intervals: compact/responsive design ?

Tags: responsive-design, forms

We have to display intervalls to the user to choose from:

less than 1250, 1250 to 5000, 5000 to 10000, 10000 to 50000, 50000 to 100000 and over 100000

I thaught of something like this

*1250   5000     10000    50000   100000*
---()---|---()---|-----()-----|---()-----|---()-----|---()--

(): being radio buttons

I am not sure that it's intuitive enough ? And on mobiles I will have to shrink the space between intervalls and/or alternate the labels up and down.

Do you have some ideas for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I suggest to eliminate zeros by depicting them as k for every 1000.
   1.25k-5k-10k-50k-100k-more
2. As well you can use prefix x1000 as on picture below -

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea to save up some space ... thx

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for simple vertical list. Boring, perhaps, but something everyone would be accustomed to and likely easier to handle on a narrow display:

```
( ) < 1250
( ) 1,250 - 5,000
( ) 5,000 to 10,000
( ) 10,000 to 50,000
( ) 50,000 to 100,000
( ) > 100,000
```

If vertical space is also a concern, perhaps a drop down--though those can be a bit more tedious to deal with on a mobile device.

Note: I don't know the full context, but check that you an repeat the same number in two ranges (such as 5,000...you may have to make one 4,999)

Comment: Thx ... That's what I did first but I have 5 of this blocks next to each other. It didn't look good.